# Can use a head variable as a functor name in a body?

Tags: prolog

Prolog lets us unify compound terms to variables:

```
token(1,2,3).
token(4,5,6).

token_term(Term, X, Y, Z) :- Term=token(X, Y, Z).
```

```
? token_term(Term, 1,2,3).
T = token(1, 2, 3).
```

How can we make a more general version for any functor name:

```
? term(Term, token, 1,2,3).
T = token(1, 2, 3).
```

It seems the following is not allowed syntax:

```
term(Term, F, X, Y, Z) :- Term=F(X, Y, Z).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Predicate =../2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%3D../2)

Comment: `term(Term, F, X, Y, Z) :- Term =.. [F,X,Y,Z].`  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this in the first place? In many situations you do not want to construct a compound term, instead, you might want to construct a goal. So instead of

```
term(Term, F, X, Y, Z) :- Term=F(X, Y, Z).
```

you may say:

```
term(call(F,X,Y,Z), F, X, Y, Z).
```

The resulting term will be callable in precisely that way, the compound term would be called.

```
?- term(G_0, token, 1, 2, 3).
   G_0 = call(token, 1, 2, 3).
```

There is no difference between this term and `token(1, 2, 3)` when you just call then,

Comment: `term(call(F,X,Y,Z), F, X, Y, Z).` in your example still needs to define `term(...)`. Did you mean just `call(F,X,Y,Z)` 
`?- call(foo, 1,2,3).` gives true/false, not `foo(1,2,3)` if `foo(1,2,3)` can be satisfied.

Comment: `term(Goal_0, token, 1, 2, 3)` succeeds with `Goal_0 = call(token, 1, 2, 3)` which when called, is the same as `token(1, 2, 3)` so there is no need to "define" term.

Comment: `term` is the rule I'm trying to define. It can't be parameter. If  `assert(f(1,2,3)).` then `? call(f, 1, 2, 3).` just returns true. What I want to retrieve is functor-term involving f.  ... What I want is some predicate `x(G, F, ARG0, ARG1, ARG2)` that yields as the result of a query `G=F(X,Y,Z)` if `F(X,Y,Z)`  is true, (I don't want to yield `G=true` if `F(X,Y,Z)` can be found).

Comment: Oh wait.. 
You mean the query should be:
`Goal_0 = call(f, 1, 2, 3).`
That's right, for queries. But I'm interested in rules that talk about functors as parameters (meta programming/function template parameters).

Comment: @user48956: Exactly in many cases of meta programming, this version is often preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GuyCoder

```
% Convert F, [X_0, X_1, ....] into a term
% if a match can be made.
% e.g. term(T, tok, [1,2,3])  --> tok(1,2,3) IFF tok(1,2,3)
find_term(Term, F, X) :- Term =.. [F|X], Term.

% Term constructor
term(Term, F, X) :- Term =.. [F|X].
```

```
?- assertz(token(4,5,6)).
true.

?- assertz(token(1,2,3)).
true.

?- find_term(T, token, [1,_,_]).
T = token(1, 2, 3).

?- find_term(T, token, [_,_,_]).
T = token(4, 5, 6) ;
T = token(1, 2, 3).
```